# Why am I getting "Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame."

Tags: kivy

I'm just learning, and I tried to run this simple code

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Header(Widget):
    pass


class PingStat(Widget):
    pass


class MyPingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        c = BoxLayout()
        a = PingStat()
        b = Header()
        c.add_widget(a)
        c.add_widget(b)
        return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyPingApp().run()
```

MyPing.kv :

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Header>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1

    Label:
        font_size: 30
        text: "Pinger"
        center: 100, 100

<PingStat>
    Label:
        text: "This"
        center: 100, 500

    Label:
        text: "wat"
        center: 300, 500
```

The console repeatedly gives this error, but the window pops up just fine:

> [CRITICAL          ] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done
>   before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the
>   Clock.max_iteration attribute

Comment: I don't know what creates this warning, but delete the unnecessary part from `build` method, and move it to kv.

Comment: If the error appears just once, don't worry about it. It's just a warning, and only a problem if it's happening every frame.

Comment: This sometimes happened to me with large loops or with `center`, though I don't quite remember if it was the real problem with `center`, or just messed up code. Try to set `pos` manually(e.g. `pos: 300-self.width/2, 500-self.height/2`) and check if the warning is still there.